# How to declare String only in PHP method argument?

Tags: php, string, type-hinting

I'm trying to use this method :

```
public function setMessage(string $message){
    $this->message = $message;
}
```

Then I get this error :

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to notifier::setMessage()
>   must be an instance of string, string given

Apparently PHP is interpreting `string` as class name. Is there a look like solution to make that kind of declaration ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typehinting can only be used on objects, with the exception of arrays.

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php):

> Type hints can not be used with scalar types such as int or string. Traits are not allowed either.

Comment: The only exception is `array`.

Comment: In other words: typehinging works for non-scalar types only.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a loosely typed language, it doesn't really care about the type and will guess anyways. You can only limit variables to classes at the function declaration, so remove the `string` and everything will be fine. :)

If you really want to be sure it is a string use [gettype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) or [cast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) the variable to a string.

Note (from type-juggline on PHP.net):

> Instead of casting a variable to a string, it is also possible to
>   enclose the variable in double quotes.

```
$foo = 10;            // $foo is an integer
$str = "$foo";        // $str is a string
$fst = (string) $foo; // $fst is also a string
```